# Installing Miracle Cast on Ubuntu 18.04.2 LTS

Tags: software-installation

How to make the Miracast app "Miraclecast" work on an Ubuntu 18.04.2 LTS system? I followed the instructions listed below:

1. Go to https://github.com/albfan/miraclecast.
2. Download the entire source code, not just `autogen.sh`. You can do it by clicking the Clone or download button, and then Download as ZIP or directly at https://github.com/albfan/miraclecast/archive/master.zip.
3. Unzip the folder to get folder miraclecast-master and run:

   ```
   cd miraclecast-master
   sudo apt-get update
   sudo apt-get install ubuntu-dev-tools autoconf libtool libudev-dev libsystemd-dev glib-2.0 libperl-dev libgtk2.0-dev libreadline-dev
   libtoolize; aclocal; autoconf
   sudo ./autogen.sh
   ```
4. Once `./autogen.sh` is complete, run:

   ```
   sudo ./configure
   sudo make
   sudo make install
   ```

and I followed these steps but had an error on:

```
sudo apt-get install ubuntu-dev-tools autoconf libtool libudev-dev libsystemd-dev glib-2.0 libperl-dev libgtk2.0-dev libreadline-dev
libtoolize; aclocal; autoconf
```

But got past it by adding a `;` at the line break -

```
sudo apt-get install ubuntu-dev-tools autoconf libtool libudev-dev libsystemd-dev glib-2.0 libperl-dev libgtk2.0-dev libreadline-dev;
libtoolize; aclocal; autoconf
```

Then finished the steps and... Nothing...

Or maybe I'm missing something???

Comment: Don't run autogen.sh or make as root; its not necessary and especially autogen might Do The Wrong Thing.

Answer (score 3):

Don't use `;` to separate these: they will turn libraries into commands.

Use the following commands instead:

```
sudo apt-get install ubuntu-dev-tools autoconf libtool libudev-dev libsystemd-dev glib-2.0 libperl-dev libgtk2.0-dev libreadline-dev 
libtoolize 
aclocal 
autoconf
```